# Trying to verify person specific url then bring up login screen in Android

Tags: android, database, networking, web, connection

I'm trying to make an application where the person connects to their specific website and can then access the data from it. The first page asks them to put in the url. I then parse this and need to verify the url's existence so I can move them to the login screen. How do I go about doing this? I'm trying HttpURLConnections but I'm not having much luck. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
try {

int status = 0;
try {
    HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
    "http://www.google.com").openConnection();
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            Log.e("StatusCode",httpConnection.getResponseCode());

            if ((httpConnection.getResponseCode() == 200)||(httpConnection.getResponseCode() == 302)) {
                status = 1;
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {}
        if (status == 1) {
            Log.e("WebSite","Found");
        } else {
            Log.e("WebSite","NotFound");
        }

} catch (Exception ex1) {
Log.e("Error",ex1.getMessage().toString());
}
```